# Promise reject is very slow on Node.JS <= 18

Tags: node.js, promise

Just run it in the Node.JS <= 18:

**test.js**

```js
function delay(time) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, time)
  })
}

async function test() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      reject('value')
    })
      .then(() => {}, () => {})

    // if (i % 10000 === 0) {
    //  await delay(100)
    // }
  }

  console.log('OK')

  const time0 = Date.now()
  await delay(0)
  console.log('Real delay time: ' + (Date.now() - time0))
}

test()
```

The test function will generate 1 million of Promise rejections. And after finish it will hang. It seems like the garbage collection called on idle, and it takes very long time.
If you replace the `reject` with the `resolve`, then everything will work quickly.
You can also uncomment the periodically delay, and it will work quickly. Unfortunately even this hack does not help on some browsers. Reject calls are gradually slowed down by dozens of times.

Does anyone know another way to bypass this problem?

**PS:** I'm writing a load test that checks many ways how a module works with Promise rejects. About 1.5 million variants. I can"t reduce the number of variants. I also plan to write many more similar tests in the future and I would like them to work

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly? In which path are you seeking help?

Comment: I'm writing a load test that checks many ways how a module works with Promise rejects. About 1.5 million variants. I can"t reduce the number of variants. I also plan to write many more similar tests in the future and I would like them to work.

Comment: Promise rejections are quite similar to exceptions, if you won't handle them it causes issues. In your code I see you are not handling the rejection using catch. Have you tried using it and see if it still takes long time?

Comment: Yes, you can see in the code, that the `catch` handler included into the `then` method: `.then(onfulfilled, onrejected)`. I also tried to use the `catch` method

Comment: Please re-phrase your post and enrich it with more contextual data. It is still unclear what you are trying to fulfill and what *how a module works with Promise rejects* mean exactly.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```js
function promiseRejected(reason?: any): PromiseLike<never> {
  return {
    then(_, reject): any {
      void reject(reason)
    },
  }
}

export function rejectAsResolve(resolve: (value: any) => void, reason?: any) {
  resolve(promiseRejected(reason))
}
```

and then use this instead `reject`:

```js
new Promise((resolve) => {
  rejectAsResolve(resolve, 'ERROR')
})
```

Comment: A solution to what problem, exactly? Do your programs really have issues due to `reject` being slow?

Comment: Memory leak on some platform if you use `Promise.reject()` directly. GC is not keeping up to clear the memory.

Comment: So your code running on that platform is creating so many rejections in such a short time that it overwhelms the GC? Strange.

Comment: Yes, I think it is a bug, because I can reproduce it in the Chromium 49 but it work correctly in the Chrome latest. And this bug still not fixed in NodeJS